# ayuda conectar a mysql a través de socket en lugar de TCP

Tags: php, mysql, socket, tcp

Actualmente me conecto asi a la base de datos:

```
$this->Link_ID = mysqli_connect('localhost', $DBUser, $DBPassword, $DBDatabase);
```

me han pedido que si puedo conectarme por socket en lugar de TCP, pero no lo tengo claro

Comment: Quien te lo haya pedido debería saber que para iniciar una comunicación por TCP/IP se utilizan sockets, y si no lo sabe realmente es un ...  una persona que necesita más entrenamiento.

Comment: vale por eso no me tenia mucho sentido lo que queria

Comment: Sí se puede conectar usando un socket. ¿Sabes el path del socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a la documentación de PHP sobre [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) verás que es un alias para el [constructor de la clase `mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) en la que puedes ver que se le pueden pasar hasta 6 parámetros:

```
mysqli mysqli_connect ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") 
                       [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") 
                       [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") 
                       [, string $dbname = "" 
                       [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") 
                       [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

Así los parámetros que se le pueden pasar son el servidor, el usuario, la contraseña, el nombre de la base de datos, el puerto y el socket a usar respectivamente. En el código que compartes sólo pasas los cuatro primeros.

Para conectarte a través del socket, tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
$this->Link_ID = mysqli_connect('localhost', $DBUser, $DBPassword, $DBDatabase, NULL, $socket);
```

Donde `$Socket` sería una variable con el nombre del socket creado en el sistema.

> Nota: Según [uno de los comentarios en la documentación](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#93508), puede que si pones "localhost" como el servidor no te funcione y tengas que usar "." en su lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione asi:
`$this->Link_ID = mysqli_connect(NULL, $DBUser, $DBPassword, $DBDatabase,NULL,'/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock');`

gracias a todos.